# Problem in creating forgot-password screen in python using kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm creating a new application called "MyApp".

I am creating a forgot-password-screen where I will ask the user to enter the last password he/she remembers, then a new password and finally to confirm the password.

Here is the code and an image of the login-screen and forgot-password-screen:

main.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from difflib import get_close_matches

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def forgot_pwd(self):
        self.manager.current = "forgotpwd_screen"

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ForgotPwdScreen(Screen):
    def reset_pwd(self, lastpwd, newpwd, confirmpwd):
        npwd = newpwd
        cnfpwd = confirmpwd
        lstpwd = lastpwd
        with open("passwords.txt", 'w+') as file:
            oldpassword = file.read()

            if len(get_close_matches(lstpwd, oldpassword)) > 0 :
                if npwd == cnfpwd:
                    with open("passwords.txt", 'w+') as file:
                        for line in file:
                            file.write(line.replace(oldpassword, npwd))
                else:
                    print("Invalid Pwd!")
            else:
                print("Invalid Password.")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

design.kv file:

```
<LoginScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 4
            rows: 1
            Label:
                text: "MyApp"
            Button:
                text: "LOGIN"
            Button:
                text: "CLOSE"
            Label:
                text: "Version 1.0"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            rows: 2
            Label:
                text: "User Image"
            TextInput:
                hint_text: "Enter Password"
            
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Button:
                text: "Forgot Password"
                on_press: root.forgot_pwd()

<ForgotPwdScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 4
            rows: 1
            Label:
                text: "MyApp"
            Button:
                text: "LOGIN"
            Button:
                text: "CLOSE"
            Label:
                text: "Version 1.0"
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            Label:
                text: "FORGOT PASSWORD"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            rows: 3
            Label: 
                text: "Enter last password   :"
            TextInput:
                id: lastpwd
            Label: 
                text: "New Password   : "
            TextInput:
                id: newpwd
            Label: 
                text: "Confirm New Password   :"
            TextInput:
                id: confirmpwd
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            cols: 1
            Button:
                text: "DONE"
                on_press: root.reset_pwd(root.ids.lastpwd.text, root.ids.newpwd.text, root.ids.confirmpwd.text)
            
<RootWidget>:
    LoginScreen:
        name: "login_screen"
    ForgotPwdScreen:
        name: "forgotpwd_screen"
```

passwords.txt file:

```
admin
```

screen_image:

1. LoginScreen

[Please click this link to view screenshot of login screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZKXL.png)

2. Forgot Password Screen

[Please click this link to view screenshot of forgot password screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vercd.png)

Problem:

I want that when user gives input in all three inputboxes and clicks done, then the program should use the get_close_matches function to compare the lastpwd(i,e Enter last password) with the text in the passwords.txt file which I have created and I have also given a default password as 'admin' in the txt file. So, If it's len value is greater than 0, then it should check whether npwd(new password) and cnfpwd(confirm password) are same, if they are same, then it should replace the original text in the passwords.txt file with the npwd(newpassword) that user has entered.

But when I execute the program and give correct lastpassword and enter new and confirm password and click done, it removes the original password(i.e 'admin') from the passwords.txt file but it doesn't add the new password in the file.

I haven't got any errors. Please execute this code to see more clearly what I'm trying to tell.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are opening the `passwords.txt` file with `mode` of `w+`. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open):

> 'w'     open for writing, truncating the file first

So, the entire contents of the file are truncated before you try to read it. I suggest modifying the `reset_pwd()` method to something like:

```
def reset_pwd(self, lastpwd, newpwd, confirmpwd):
    npwd = newpwd
    cnfpwd = confirmpwd
    lstpwd = lastpwd
    with open("passwords.txt", 'r') as file:
        oldpassword = file.read()

    if len(get_close_matches(lstpwd, [oldpassword])) > 0 :
        if npwd == cnfpwd:
            with open("passwords.txt", 'w+') as file:
                    file.write(npwd)
        else:
            print("Invalid Pwd!")
    else:
        print("Invalid Password.")
```

This uses `r` for the `mode` when reading the file.

Note that the second arg to `get_close_matches()` must be a list. If you pass a string (like just using `oldpassword`), each letter in the old password will get compared to `lstpwd`.

Also, logic of comparing passwords does not need to be within the first `with open()` code block, since you are reading the entire file at once.

The above code should work OK for just a single password in the file. But, will require modification to handle a file with more than one password.

Comment: Thanks John. It helped me a lot in clearing my doubt. It also gave me some new things to learn in programming.